# How can I upgrade the iconv module in a PHP installation?

Tags: php, iconv

I am trying to install PHP on a windows 2003 server with iconv library version 2.5. However, if I download the PHP 5.2.13 binaries and try to install it, the iconv library version is listed as 1.1.

Is there anyway to upgrade this module alone? Am I missing something?